# WORDPRESS: Trying to Display Logged in Users Author Link to Their Posts

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get people who are logged in, a link to their posts.

I've done this so far:

```
<div class="widget-button"><?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo
'<a href="http://bettinganswers.co.uk/author/".$current_user->display_name.""
id="call_to_action"><span>Your Questions</span></a>'
}
?>
</div>
```

This code is being placed directly into the theme template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your echo statement is incorrect. If you're going to echo variables without concatenation, then the string needs to be encapsulated with double quotes. You also need to end the line with a semicolon:

```
echo
"<a href=\"http://bettinganswers.co.uk/author/$current_user->display_name\"
id=\"call_to_action\"><span>Your Questions</span></a>";
```

If you don't like the way this looks, here's the same thing with concatenation:

```
echo
'<a href="http://bettinganswers.co.uk/author/'.$current_user->display_name.'"
id="call_to_action"><span>Your Questions</span></a>';
```

You might also want to consider using site_url() to build any custom links:

```
echo
'<a href="'.site_url('/author/'.$current_user->display_name).'"
id="call_to_action"><span>Your Questions</span></a>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked PERFECTLY!